# Issue with table's td element with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**HTML**

```
<table class="col-xs-12">
<tbody class="col-xs-12">
  <tr class="col-xs-12">
    <td class="col-xs-3">test</td>
    <td class="col-xs-1">tesst</td>
    <td class="col-xs-1">test</td>
    <td class="col-xs-1">test</td>
    <td class="col-xs-1">test</td>
    <td class="col-xs-1">test</td>
    <td class="col-xs-1">test</td>
    <td class="col-xs-3">test</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table,td
{
  border:1px solid black;

}
td
{
  background-color:red;
}
table
{
  background-color:green;
}
*
{
  padding : 0 !important;
  margin:0 !important;
}
```

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o30L1t70/1/)

As in fiddle you can see although sum of grid value for `td` value equals 12 but it ain't covering the entire `table` , there is left over spaces (green background area) at the end of the `table`? Why ?How to overcome this issue?

**edit**

As **ShinDarth** suggested

> You should always wrap the columns (col-*) inside a row:

but I don't agree to him , I have created another fiddle now replacing `table` element with `div`, now why this difference?

[Update Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o30L1t70/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You should always wrap the columns (col-*) inside a row:

```
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr class="row">
    <td class="col-xs-3">test</td>
    <td class="col-xs-1">tesst</td>
    <td class="col-xs-1">test</td>
    <td class="col-xs-1">test</td>
    <td class="col-xs-1">test</td>
    <td class="col-xs-1">test</td>
    <td class="col-xs-1">test</td>
    <td class="col-xs-3">test</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o30L1t70/2/

Comment: Edited the question ,please check

Answer (score 0):

All you needed, to add class `table` into `table` tag instead `col-xs-12`. In this case other classes `col-xs-12` are extra too:

```
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="col-xs-3">test</td>
      <td class="col-xs-1">tesst</td>
      <td class="col-xs-1">test</td>
      <td class="col-xs-1">test</td>
      <td class="col-xs-1">test</td>
      <td class="col-xs-1">test</td>
      <td class="col-xs-1">test</td>
      <td class="col-xs-3">test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[JSfiddle-example](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/o30L1t70/4/)